# Prevent R install.packages() method from changing repos

Tags: r, install.packages

For security reasons, we have created our own mini CRAN repository. I would like to prevent R packages from being installed from any location other than our repository, whether this is from a tar file on their desktop or an actual CRAN repository. We have set

```
local({r <- getOption("repos")
       r["CRAN"] <- "http://fakecran.com/R/cran/"
       options(repos=r)})
```

in the `RProfile.site`. However, the problem is that they can still change `getOption("repos")` to whatever they want and they can also specify a location using `install.packages(repos="http://cran.r-project.org")`. Is there any way to override these methods in `RProfile.site` (which our users are unable to access)in such a way that they can't then be overridden again?

Comment: As long as users have internet access there is no perfect security. You could change the source of `install.packages` for every R installation and hard-code your own repository.

Comment: in what way is downloading statistics code from cran a security risk?

Comment: @rawr - it's code. It does what it wants.  It can destroy you.  Seriously though it can be a security risk.  I can think of ways to make it *harder* for a user to download from CRAN but am having trouble thinking of ways of making it impossible.

Comment: http://tinfoilhat.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, you could blacklist all CRAN mirrors on your proxy.

Comment: @Roland It's a start but that doesn't take care of the problem of users installing locally from a tar/zip

Comment: @rawr There are concerns because it's open source. I completely agree that the risk is low, but with some of the R packages having C in them, it's possible that something malicious could be in there. We have to scan anything that comes in.

Comment: @Roland So we did think about going that route but someone could email something to themselves if they wanted it and then load it from their desktop with repos as well. Then you also have to keep up with the possible changes in CRAN mirrors, which is ultimately why I was trying to override

Comment: I hear that argument a bit. "We don't trust it *because* it's open source".  Makes me chuckle because the implication is that the code that you trust is the code that people aren't willing to show you :D

Comment: @Dason I agree. Malicious code can be inserted into any code and be very difficult to find. In this case though, we do pretty comprehensive scans and security checks for every third party piece of software we use. This is really just about being able to scan every package before our users use it.

Comment: Oh I understand - I just find that argument that it's untrusted *because* it's open source to be silly.  In this case it's more untrusted because there the code in packages comes with no guarantees. Like I said I can think of ways to make it harder but am having trouble thinking of a foolproof way that would make it impossible to install packages. I mean a user could conceivably even unpack the package and place it in their library without ever needing to use `install.packages` or `R CMD INSTALL`.

Comment: @Dason And I'd be pretty happy to hear about how to make it _harder_ to download from CRAN. Honestly, I just have to mitigate how I can and then other people will make the decision whether or not it's enough to use R. I would hate, as a company, not being able to use R because of something highly unlinkely.

Comment: Not a developed idea, but `install.packages=function(pkgs, lib, repos, ...) { stopifnot(identical(repos, "http://my.repos")); utils::install.packages(pkgs, lib, repos, ...) }`; use site Rprofile / Renviron to place in front of utils on `search()`; expose R through a script that strips --vanilla, --no-site-file, etc options. Beware of `source()`, which evaluates arbitrary R code from a URL. Wait for irritated users wondering why R is broken, install their own R (not hard), etc. Alternative: run R in a docker or other container where the user can do whatever damage they want.

Comment: @MartinMorgan It took some playing around, but I went with your first option. In our environment, it's exceedingly difficult to install any software, even through command line. I also asked others if we talk about the last solution, which I think is the best, but they said that transporting potentially sensitive data outside of our work environment is a no go. As an aside, I sent my wife, who works with gene/metabolomics sequencing for MS stuff to your website.